# HTML Table inside JQuery Dialog not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make my table popup using a JQuery Dialog on clicking a button. However it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code:

**HTML for button**

```
<div class="inner2">
    <p><button class="more comment"><img src="images/more.png"></button>Some random text here</p>
</div>
```

**HTML for Table I want to popup on button click**

```
<div id="dialog-modal" style="display:none">
    <table class="innerTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="infoHead">
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Pseudo</td>
            </tr>               
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tom Cruise</td>
                <td>BOB</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JQuery Script**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $( ".comment").click(function(){ 
           $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
              height: 140,
              modal: true
            });
           $( "#dialog-modal" ).show();
        });
     });
</script>
```

When I click nothing happens. I did import my Jquery library because other Jquery stuff are working except for this one. So I think I may be doing something wrong here.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in your developer tools? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @KevinBoucher I use notepad to write my code :S I'm really not sure how to test that to be honest.

Comment: Do you use Firefox? Or Chrome? Learn how to use the built-in development tools in these browsers. You will learn a lot and they will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Okay I see what you meant. I learned ho to use the console just now and here's the error it shows:
TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
Any Idea what could be wrong? The function looks fine to me.

Comment: Did you embed the jQuery UI script (that dialog functionality is part of) properly …?

Comment: ^^^ What he said. You do not have jQueryUI loaded. (It is a separate library from jQuery)

Comment: @CBroe If that's what you're talking about then yes:
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @KevinBoucher I'm pretty sure I did check above comment.

Comment: Difficult to tell w/o seeing your markup. Code looks good. Are you loading the jqueryUI script after the jquery script? Are you loading both of these after your markup?

Comment: @KevinBoucher Loading the JQuery UI after my JQuery script. They are both loaded inside <head> so it sholdn't be affecting anything. It's weird though.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Alright it seems to work now. I tried to use another version and it magically works. But now the problem is it doesn't popup but breaks my html and appears all the way down. Is that normal?

Comment: Probably still missing the jQuery UI _CSS_ then …

Comment: @CBroe I'm using the following. It still break and doesn't popup:

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"></script>

Comment: CSS is not embedded via `script` elements …

Comment: @CBroe I realized it and came back to edit my comment. *Facepalm* I think I should get away from my machine for some time. Thanks for the help though. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the jQuery UI library added to your document?

I copied your code and added the jquery ui library and it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
       $( ".comment").click(function(){ 
           $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
              height: 140,
              modal: true
            });
           $( "#dialog-modal" ).show();
        });
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inner2">
    <p><button class="more comment"><img src="images/more.png"></button>Some random text here</p>
    <div id="dialog-modal" style="display:none">
    <table class="innerTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="infoHead">
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Pseudo</td>
            </tr>               
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tom Cruise</td>
                <td>BOB</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5tumouL/1/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't load [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/). It add `dialog` support.

http://jsfiddle.net/dvxw6okq/ (note: "jQuery UI 1.9.2" is checked)

Answer (score -1):

In this piece of code, you set the display attribute of the `css` to none.

```
<div id="dialog-modal" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Try setting the display to block.

```
$(function() {
   $( ".comment").click(function(){ 
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
          height: 140,
          modal: true
        });
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).css("display", "block");
       $( "#dialog-modal" ).show();
    });
 });
```

I think that should fix it.